# How do I pan a map so all markers are always visible when a div partially covers the map? (Google Maps API v3)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a div containing the map set to 100% width and height, taking up the entire viewport. A menu animates in on top of the map. When users click one of the markers on the map, another div loads next to the menu with content.

When the content div is loaded, I want the map to pan and zoom so that all the markers fit in the remaining space that the user can still see. The div sizes are done on percentages, so the remaining space is 40% of the viewport. When the content div is closed I'd like it to do the same again, this time making use of the extra space.

I'm struggling to get my head around how to do this. I assume I need to define the boundaries in pixel coordinates and then use fitToBounds()?

Answer (score 2):

It would need testing, but I think fitBounds will take into account real controls you have on the map.

So maybe you could make your div a custom control.

Answer (score 0):

Make your content div an overlayview.

That should let google maps deal with it in the viewport correctly.